# Model or algorithm for a balanced graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, network-flow, decision-theory

I have a graph which each nodes has the following features:

- A node can produce some "energy" (or something like that);
- A node has to satisfy the need energy and so use the energy produced for itself;

So each node has $\Delta E$ represents the difference between the energy produced and the energy used.
Now the goal is:

- send energy to other nodes if the difference between the energy produced and the energy used is positive ($\Delta E$) and send send this energy to nodes that has $\Delta E< 0$;
- optimize this process, that is one wants there are nodes with $\Delta E \sim 0 $ as much as possibile.

Which model or algorithm can describe this problem? I think there is something like this in graph or decision theory. Any suggestions?

Comment: The optimization part is unclear to me. Do you want to keep $\Delta E$ fixed and optimize the way that energy is sent around so that you minimize the number of nodes that do not have the required amount of energy?